# Why java does not support multiple inheritance?

Tags: java

In java by default all classes are inherit from Object class and even we can also inherit the classes.

```
class A{ // default **Object class** is extended

}
class B extends A{ 
           //default **Object class** is extended and also **class A** extended.
}
```

Then why we say that java doesn't support multiple inheritance through classes?

Comment: because at some point of the inheritance chain you will get to a class that inherits from object, but you can´t inherit from two classes at the same time.

Comment: @Kevin Esche That comment is the logical fallacy known as "begging the question".

Answer (score 1):

> It is just to remove ambiguity, because multiple inheritance can cause
>   ambiguity in few scenarios. One of the most common scenario is Diamond
>   problem.

Look at this page : http://www.instanceofjava.com/2014/12/why-java-does-not-supports-multiple.html